Saving a Javascript Function on a webpage
I made a quiz, and the theme is the Harry Potter's universe.
I made a feature that allow the user to change the theme between the houses (Slytherin, Hufflepuff etc.) before starting the quiz.
But I've got a problem. Each time you press validate, to validate your answer, and a function call another question (and its answers), the theme refreshes itself and doesn't save the chosen one.
Disclaimer: It's my first post, and I'm not a native English speaker, excuse my language.
Here's my theme function. It add and replace a class to put the theme on whatever I want on the page :
// Allow to reset a theme :
function resetTheme() {
  document.querySelector('.customizable').classList.remove('Serpentard', 'Gryffondor', 'Poufsouffle', 'Serdaigle');
}

function popUp() {
  // Logique Slytherin
  document.querySelector('#Serpentard').addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.customizable')) {
      element.classList.add('Serpentard')
      console.log(element);
    }
    for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.customizable')) {
      element.classList.remove('Serdaigle', 'Gryffondor', 'Poufsouffle');
      console.log(element);
    }
  })

  // Logique Ravenclaw
  document.querySelector('#Serdaigle').addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.customizable')) {
      element.classList.add('Serdaigle')
      console.log(element);
    }
    for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.customizable')) {
      element.classList.remove('Serpentard', 'Gryffondor', 'Poufsouffle');
      console.log(element);
    }
  })

  // Logique Gryffondor
  document.querySelector('#Gryffondor').addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.customizable')) {
      element.classList.add('Gryffondor')
      console.log(element);
    }
    for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.customizable')) {
      element.classList.remove('Serdaigle', 'Serpentard', 'Poufsouffle');
      console.log(element);
    }
  })

  // Logique Hufflepuff
  document.querySelector('#Poufsouffle').addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.customizable')) {
      element.classList.add('Poufsouffle')
      console.log(element);
    }
    for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.customizable')) {
      element.classList.remove('Serdaigle', 'Gryffondor', 'Serpentard');
      console.log(element);
    }
  })
}


export default popUp;



Here is the question/answer functions :
import createQuestion from "./cardQuestion.js";
import questionsToAsk from "./questionsToAsk.js";
import displayPopup from "./popUp.js";

const QUESTIONS = document.querySelector(".blockQuestion");
const timerElement = document.getElementById('timer');
let currentQuestionIndex = 0;
let score = 0;
let timer;

// Display the question
function displayQuestion(index) {
    selectedAnswerId = null;
    QUESTIONS.innerHTML = createQuestion(questionsToAsk[index]);
    startTimer();
}

// Start the timer (between each question)
function startTimer(timeLeft = 15) {
    timerElement.innerHTML = `
        <img src="../public/images/hourglass.png" alt="Sablier" class="timer-icon">
        <span>${timeLeft}</span>
    `;
    
    timer = setInterval(() => {
        timeLeft--;
        timerElement.innerHTML = `
            <img src="../public/images/hourglass.png" alt="Sablier" class="timer-icon">
            <span>${timeLeft}</span>
        `;
        
        if (timeLeft <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            nextQuestion();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

// Display the next question :
function nextQuestion() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    currentQuestionIndex++;
    
    if (currentQuestionIndex < questionsToAsk.length) {
        displayQuestion(currentQuestionIndex);
    } else {
        showFinalScore();
    }
}

// Final score :
function showFinalScore() {
    QUESTIONS.innerHTML = `
        <h2>Quiz terminé !</h2>
        <p>Votre score : ${score} / ${questionsToAsk.length}</p>
        <button id="restart">Rejouer</button>
    `;
    document.getElementById('restart').addEventListener('click', () => {
        location.reload();
    });
}

// Verify the answer :
function checkAnswer(selectedAnswer, correctAnswer) {
    if (selectedAnswer === correctAnswer) {
        score++;
    }
    nextQuestion();
}

// Start button :
QUESTIONS.innerHTML = '<button id="start">START</button>';
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', () => {
    displayQuestion(currentQuestionIndex);
});

// Variable to stock the answer :
let selectedAnswerId = null;

// Event Listener for the event :
QUESTIONS.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('answer-btn')) {
        // Réinitialiser tous les boutons
        document.querySelectorAll('.answer-btn').forEach(btn => {
            btn.classList.remove('selected');
        });
        // Marquer le bouton cliqué comme sélectionné
        e.target.classList.add('selected');
        selectedAnswerId = e.target.id;
    } else if (e.target.id === 'validate') {
        if (selectedAnswerId) {
            const correctAnswer = questionsToAsk[currentQuestionIndex].lienValider.slice(1);
            checkAnswer(selectedAnswerId, correctAnswer);
        } else {
            alert("Veuillez sélectionner une réponse avant de valider !");
        }
    }
});

displayPopup();





main page :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Modal</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSerpentard.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Serdaigle">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Gryffondor">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Poufsouffle">
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="twp-container">
    <div id="twp-overlay">
        <div id="twp-popup">
            <h2 id="twp-popup-title">Greetings, wizard</h2>
            <p class="twp-intro">It seems distraction is on the horizon. Before moving ahead, consider: is this the best direction for your attention right now, or might there be other ways to use this moment?</p>
            <p class="twp-full-quote">As the old adage reminds us, “<span class="twp-quote">We may encounter many defeats but we must not be defeated.</span>”</p>
            <div id="twp-popup-footer"><button id="Serdaigle">Serdaigle</button></div>
            <div id="twp-popup-footer"><button id="Serpentard">Serpentard</button></div>
            <div id="twp-popup-footer"><button id="Poufsouffle">Poufsouffle</button></div>
            <div id="twp-popup-footer"><button id="Gryffondor">Gryffondor</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

      <article class="question customizable">
        <fieldset class="listReponse customizable">
          <legend>${question.legend}</legend>

          <button class="answer-btn customizable" id="R1" name="answer">${question.R1}</button>
          <button class="answer-btn customizable" id="R2" name="answer">${question.R2}</button>
          <button class="answer-btn customizable" id="R3" name="answer">${question.R3}</button>
          <button class="answer-btn customizable" id="R4" name="answer">${question.R4}</button>

        </fieldset>
        
          <button id="validate">VALIDER</button>
        
      
      </article>

</body>
</html>


// CardQuestion :
function createQuestion(question) {
  let addQuestion =`
      <article class="question">
        <fieldset class="listReponse">
          <legend>${question.legend}</legend>

          <button class="answer-btn" id="R1" name="answer">${question.R1}</button>
          <button class="answer-btn" id="R2" name="answer">${question.R2}</button>
          <button class="answer-btn" id="R3" name="answer">${question.R3}</button>
          <button class="answer-btn" id="R4" name="answer">${question.R4}</button>

        </fieldset>
        
          <button id="validate">VALIDER</button>
        
      
      </article>`;
  
  return addQuestion;
}

export default createQuestion;

My challenge is to put everything on the same page.
Any idea ?
Was I clear ?
Thanks in advance, best regards,
a beginner ^^
I created everything from scratch, and it pretty much worked until I realised the house theme wasn't save anywhere.
I'm a beginner, I started JS 3 weeks ago, so be easy on me.
If you have any clue, anything at all, I'll take it.
Best wishes for you work and mine !

You can use localStorage to save settings such as this.

But in trying to run your code here, a.) QUESTIONS is null and b.) you should include your css too.

You shouldn't need to use location.reload() after changing the theme. Just reset all the global variables. If you're changing classes and want the event listeners to follow those changes, you should use event delagation instead of adding listeners to specific elements.

You just gave me something to chew over night.
Thank you !

You can greatly shorten function popUp by not repeating similar code. That's the important thing. As for saving the theme
you can use localStorage.setItem("myTheme", theme). In order to retrieve the theme, after load, you can use theme = localStorage.getItem("myTheme")


function popUp() {

  var themes = ["Serpentard", "Serdaigle", "Gryffondor", "Poufsouffle"];

  themes.forEach(function(theme) {
    document.querySelector('#' + theme).addEventListener('click', () => {
      for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.customizable')) {
        element.classList.remove(...themes);
        element.classList.add(theme)
        console.log(element);
      }
    })
  })

}




Alright, I get it.
Gonna try it soon tomorrow (it's 11pm here)
Thanks a lot IT goldman, looking forward to test this :)
